# SwiftUI NavigationBarItems slideBack freezes app

Tags: ios, swiftui, navigationbar, back-button

My `HomeView` (where I store list of `Movies`) has `NavigationView` and `NavigationLink` with destination to `DetailView`.

When I want to add `NavigationBarItems` in my `DetailView`, it makes my *GoBack Slide* (from `DetailView` to `HomeView`) useless. The app freezes when I stop sliding in ~1/3 of screen.

I don't have additional `NavigationView` in `DetailView`, because when I had it I had it doubled in `DetailView`.

I found lines of code which ruins everything.

It's part with `NavigationBarItems`:

```
.navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
    self.showingEditScreen.toggle()
}) {
    Image(systemName: "pencil")
    .imageScale(.large)
    .accessibility(label: Text("Edit Movie"))
    .padding()
})
```

And `HomeView`:

```
struct HomeView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc

    @FetchRequest(entity: Movie.entity(), sortDescriptors: [
        NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Movie.title, ascending: true),
        NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Movie.director, ascending: true)
    ]) var movies: FetchedResults<Movie>

    @State private var showingAddScreen = false

    func deleteMovie(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        for offset in offsets {

            let movie = movies[offset]

            moc.delete(movie)
        }
        try? moc.save()
    }


    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(movies, id: \.self) { movie in
                    NavigationLink(destination: DetailMovieView(movie: movie)) {
                        EmojiRatingView(rating: movie.rating)
                            .font(.largeTitle)
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            Text(movie.title ?? "Unknown Title")
                                .font(.headline)
                            Text(movie.director ?? "Unknown Director")
                                .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .onDelete(perform: deleteMovie)
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Movie Store")
            .navigationBarItems(leading: EditButton(), trailing: Button(action: {
                self.showingAddScreen.toggle()
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "plus")
                    .imageScale(.large)
                    //.accessibility(label: Text("Add Movie"))
                    .padding()
            })
                .sheet(isPresented: $showingAddScreen) {
                    AddMovieView().environment(\.managedObjectContext,     self.moc)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we see your `HomeView`?

Comment: I've added HomeView to question

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in your code, unless you have millions of movies. Which Xcode version do you use? Did you perform anything in Details or just navigate forward and backward?

Comment: I have Xcode 11.2.1
In Detail I have details of Movie, button with EditingSheet, button which deleting that movie and I can navigate between Home and Detail.
When I've put Edit Button as an element of View, it works fine but If I put Edit Sheet Button on NavigationBarItem, it doesn't work - button works, but app freezes sometimes

Comment: Also I can't replicate any freezing because I don't know what your `AddMovieView()` is doing.

Comment: Also you're saying that the issue relates to the editing functionality. Can you provide some more logic around that?

Comment: @Maciekx7 Have you figured this out? I'm running into a semi-similar problem, where essentially, putting custom navigation buttons in the nav bar causes a whole whack of problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is currently a bug with SwiftUI. If you have a `.sheet` and/or a `.alert` in your `DetailView`, remove them and it will work as expected, without the app freezing.