# App freezes using @Environment(\.dismiss) variable, SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

The whole app is working fine and code is compiling perfectly, but when I navigate from `ServiceListView` to `EmployeeDetailView` and press any button, the CPU goes to 100% and the app freezes.

This solution [SwiftUI NavigationBarItems slideBack freezes app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59344756/swiftui-navigationbaritems-slideback-freezes-app) does not work in my case.

If I remove this `@Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss` from my `ServicesListView` view then code works fine. Any reason for it?

Similar Question is posted on Apple Forum [@Environment(.dismiss) var dismiss - Infinite loop bug](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/720803)

[image]

Service List View

```swift
struct ServicesListView: AppTNowView {
    
    var services: [Service] = []
    var isAvailableNowView = false
    
    @State private var moveToEmployeeDetail = false
    @State private var isCallingFirstTime = true
    
    @StateObject var viewModel =  ServicesListViewModel()
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            loadView
            LoaderView(isLoading: $viewModel.showLoader)
        }.alert(isPresented: $viewModel.showError, content: {
            Alert(title: Text(viewModel.errorMessage))
        }).onAppear{
            if isCallingFirstTime {
                viewModel.selectedServiceID = services.first?.id ?? 0
                viewModel.selectedService = services.first
                fetchEmployee()
                isCallingFirstTime.toggle()
            }
            
        }.onChange(of: viewModel.selectedServiceID, perform: { newValue in
            debugPrint("Appt: selected index \(newValue)")
            viewModel.selectedServiceID = newValue
            viewModel.selectedService = services.first(where: {$0.id == newValue})
            fetchEmployee()
        })
    }
}
```

Code for performing navigation into the ServiceListView.

```swift
ScrollView {
    if viewModel.employeeList.isEmpty {
        EmptyListView(imageName: ImageName.Home.noEmployee.rawValue, descriptionText: "No Employees available against this service")
            .padding(.top, 50)
    } else {
        VStack {
            ForEach(viewModel.employeeList) { employee in
                NavigationLink {
                    EmployeeDetailView(employee: employee)
                        .hideNavigationBar
                } label: {
                    EmployeeInfoCardView(employee: employee)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my `EmployeeDetailView`

```swift
struct EmployeeDetailView: AppTNowView {
    
    @State private var isCalanderPresented = false
    @StateObject var viewModel = EmployeeDetailViewModle()
    @FocusState private var isMessageFocused: Bool
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    var employee: Employee
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            loadView
            LoaderView(isLoading: $viewModel.showLoader)
        }
        .alert(isPresented: $viewModel.showError, content: {
            Alert(title: Text(viewModel.errorMessage))
        })
        .sheet(isPresented: $isCalanderPresented) {
            CalanderView(date: $viewModel.selecteDate, isCalanderPresented: $isCalanderPresented)
                .presentationDetents([.medium, .large])
                .onDisappear {
                    
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like you're facing an infinity loop somewhere. However, I cannot figure out the whole flow like this. Can you check the stack trace after the app crashes?

Comment: app in not crashing and it keep running with 100 % CPU.

Comment: @son I have added the stack trace into the question.

Comment: `hideNavigationBar` looks very suspicious

Comment: I am using it into all of my projects `hideNavigationBar ` I don't think this may cause any issue. I have tested the code even after removing this line as well. but same issue exist. @loremipsum

Comment: @koen code is tightly coupled with different view and I have tried to replicated it into simple project but the behaviour is unexpected. I am going to share the github link of project so that you can run the project.

Comment: @koen MLBranchSSO Package added into the description, Just drag it into your project.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255824/discussion-between-qazi-ammar-and-koen).

Comment: I found the issue if I remove this line `@Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss` from my ServicesListView then app start working fine. But now I want the solution how to move back if i did't use this. @koen @lorem ipsum

Comment: Wow, it is ridiculous that this freezes when you use `@Environment(\.dismiss)`. Great find! I'm using `@Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode` for now.

Comment: It is ridiculous .. I am facing the same issue .. As I remove the @Environment(\.dismiss) private var .. It start working

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you might need to fallback to using the older `@Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode` in the meantime.

I've been encountering the same issue with iOS 16/17 since moving to NavigationStack and I cannot pinpoint what is causing the infinite loop.

I have a sheet and push a couple views via NavigationLink, in which the app freezes when presenting the second consecutive NavigationLink. Classic SwiftUI.

Another two other alternative approaches, if you omit `dismiss` and don't want to use `presentationMode`;

1. if you can get a reference to the active view controller, you can directly call `.dismiss(animated: animated)` to immediately dismiss the VC
2. if you want to pop rather than dismiss, get a reference to the VC and call `let nc = vc?.children.first as? UINavigationController` to get the child navigation controller, and then `nc?.popViewController(animated: true)` to pop it one view back.

Comment: Similar situation, but in my case the app didn't freeze, simply an error with 42 code appears in the console. Solved using the old presentationMode until Apple fix the bug.