# SwiftUI app crashes when using @Environment(\.dismiss) with NavigationView/NavigationStack

Tags: swiftui, crash

I don't know why but this simple SwiftUI app crashes when I click the button saying "This is sheet one, click to open sheet two".
The crash message is:

> "Application tried to present modally a view controller <*TtGC7SwiftUI29PresentationHostingControllerVS_7AnyView*: 0x151008a00> that is already being presented by <*TtGC7SwiftUI19UIHostingControllerGVS_15ModifiedContentVS_7AnyViewVS_12RootModifier*_: 0x14e013a00>."

```swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct MyApp: App {
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            // Both NavigationView and NavigationStack give a crash
            NavigationView {
//          NavigationStack {
                A()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct A: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: B(), label: {
            Text("Go Inside")
        })
    }
}

struct B: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    enum BottomSheetType : String, Identifiable {
        case one, two
        
        var id: String {
            self.rawValue
        }
    }
    
    @State var bottomSheetType : BottomSheetType? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            
            Button(action: {
                bottomSheetType = .one
            },
                   label: {
                Text("Click to open sheet A")
            })
        }
        
        .sheet(item: $bottomSheetType) { bottomSheetType in
            switch bottomSheetType{
                
            case .one:
                Button("This is sheet one, click to open sheet two") {
                    self.bottomSheetType = .two
                }
                
            case .two:
                Text("This is sheet two")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I remove the line `@Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss` from view B, it works fine.
But I can not understand the reason behind the crash. Also I will be using that `dismiss` variable later so I can't remove it just to avoid the crash.

Comment: I tried your code in XCode 14.2 simulator, `NavigationStack` variant works as expected. `NavigationView` variant no crash, but view `B` is "bouncing", i.e. constantly being automatically dismissed and presented. Erratic behaviour stops when removing the `dismiss` declaration. `NavigationView` is *deprecated* anyways.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77401804/app-freezes-after-performing-navigation-with-navigationstack/77414367#77414367